# How to get a collection of (key,value) from a dictionary where key contains a substring?

Tags: c#

I have a `Dictionary<string, string>` in which I am storing paths to my configuration files like:

```
Config0, <some path>
Config1, <some path>
Config2, <some path>
Someconfigkey, <some path>
Someconfigkey, <some path>
Someconfigkey, <some path>
...
...
```

I want to get all the key,values from this dictionary for keys that contain substring `Config`

Any recommendations how to do this efficiently?

Comment: What do you mean “efficiently”? There nothing better than O(n) here...

Comment: Remember, a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` implements the `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>` interface. Which means there is nothing stopping you from using Linq methods to find/select/filter key-value-pairs based on whatever predicate you provide...

Comment: It feels like there may be a better starting point. Redesign the data structures perhaps? Also, what is the size of the problem: perhaps O(n) would be efficient enough.

Comment: How is this a duplicate of the question linked here ?! I am asking for (Key,Value) from the keys that contains a substring provided. The linked 'duplicate' is NOT the SAME!

Comment: @Monku it's the same principle - you have to loop through the keys (or use a Linq query which loops for you).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code exempt will create a new dictionary based on another dictionary.

```
Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
        { "Config0", "0" },
        { "Config1", "1" },
        { "AnotherKey", "2" },
        { "SomeOtherKey", "3" }
};

Dictionary<string, string> configOnlyDictionary = dict.Where(x => x.Key.Contains("Config")).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

Comment: This has the same drawback  - it's still iterating through all the keys

Comment: @PeterSmith It has the benefit of being copy/pastable without having to think about whether it's efficient or not.

Comment: Agreed - its just that the question said 'efficient'. However, I did upvote your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Since the keys are hashed by their value, if you're not searching for exact key values you'll need to loop through the whole collection of key/value pairs:

```
foreach (var kvp in dict)
{
    if(kvp.Key.Contains(term))
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

You *could* convert this to a Linq query with `Where`, but from an *efficiency* standpoint it's no better than a loop.

If you *consistently* search for the substring `Config`, then you could try using *two* dictionaries: a "config" dictionary and a "non-config" dictionary. It would still be O(n) to loop through each of them but you'd only be looping through the entries that you *know* contain the substring (your "n" will be smaller).